# TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null. (line 59) + 1 other error

Tags: javascript, api, gmail, google-apps-script

I have minimal knowledge of Javascript, but would like to use this code to enhance my GMail experience. It works, but I also get errors. When I run the debugger in Google Spreadsheet, two functions appear to malfunction:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null. (line 59)

With the following Execution transcript

> GmailApp.getUserLabelByName([FollowUp])
>
> GmailApp.getUserLabelByName([FollowUp/1undefined])

*Inserted comment:* there is some information about the GMail API call getThreads (and others) here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmaillabel#getThreads

What I don't get is why it is calling Followup/1undefined -> why is it undefined? It should be Followup/1days

And another error with another function:

> Cannot find method moveThreadsToInbox(. (line 26)

With nothing in the Execution transcript

The entire code is:

```js
// Adapted from:
// http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/gmail-snooze-with-apps-script.html
//
// To setup:
// - From the |Run| menu select |setup|
//   - if prompted to authorize, do so, and then repeat this step.
//
// - Verify the script is set to be triggered to run
//   - |Triggers| menu |Current script's triggers...|
//   - 3 triggers should exist to call e.g. 
//     - dailyUpdate, Time Driven, Daily

function getLabelName(i, labelSuffixString) {
  return "FollowUp/" + i + labelSuffixString;
}

function setup() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    GmailApp.createLabel(getLabelName(i, "days"));
    GmailApp.createLabel(getLabelName(i, "weeks"));
  }
  GmailApp.createLabel("FollowUp");
}

function moveToInbox(page) {
  GmailApp.moveThreadsToInbox(page);
  GmailApp.markThreadsImportant(page);
}

function cleanOldFollowUpLabels() {
  var searchString = "-label:inbox label:FollowUp";
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    searchString += " -label:" + getLabelName(i, "days");
    searchString += " -label:" + getLabelName(i, "weeks");
  }
  searchString = searchString.replace(RegExp("/", "g"), "-");
  Logger.log("cleanOldFollowUpLabels() Search String:");
  Logger.log(searchString);
  var followUpLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FollowUp");  
  var page = null;
  // Get threads in "pages" of 100 at a time
  while(!page || page.length == 100) {
    page = GmailApp.search(searchString, 0, 100);
    Logger.log("found: " + page.length);
    if (page.length > 0)
      followUpLabel.removeFromThreads(page);   
  }
}

function update(labelSuffixString) {
  var oldLabel, newLabel, page;
  var followUpLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FollowUp");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    newLabel = oldLabel;
    oldLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(getLabelName(i, labelSuffixString));
    page = null;
    // Get threads in "pages" of 100 at a time
    while(!page || page.length == 100) {
      page = oldLabel.getThreads(0, 100);
      if (page.length > 0) {
        followUpLabel.addToThreads(page);
        if (newLabel) {
          // Move the threads into "today’s" label
          newLabel.addToThreads(page);
        } else {
          moveToInbox(page);
        }     
        // Move the threads out of "yesterday’s" label
        oldLabel.removeFromThreads(page);
      }  
    }
  }
}

function dailyUpdate() {
  update("days");
}
function weeklyUpdate() {
  update("weeks");
}
```

Also here: http://pastie.org/4790086.js

Comment: there is some information about the GMail API call getThreads (and others) here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_gmaillabel#getThreads

What I don't get is why it is calling Followup/1undefined -> why is it undefined? It should be Followup/1days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mm.. with the help of a colleague, we found the answer to my own problem. I had three triggers running: A daily trigger, a weekly trigger, and the update trigger. Now **the update trigger was not necessary**, because it was called upon by the daily and weekly trigger, and without any input. That caused the error. Now I have to wait and see if there are any errors and if the script works.